# gremlin query with valueMap() and toList() takes time to get result

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, janus

I am using janus graph deployed in embedded mode. And i am using java. And firing following queries

--> g.V().has('deleted',false).valueMap() //slow

--> g.V().has('deleted',false).toList()  //slow

the above query takes time after implementing composite indexes also

--> g.V().has('deleted',false)  //fast

above query is fast and use implemented composite index created on deleted key.

**Also tried the same using java code**

```
        List<Vertex> list = new ArrayList<>();

        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
        JanusGraphQuery<? extends JanusGraphQuery> query = GraphClient.getJGraph().query();
        Iterator iterator = query.has("deleted",false).vertices().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Vertex next = (Vertex) iterator.next();
            getPropertyMapByVertex(next); //time consuming to convert vertex into Map.
            list.add(next);
        }


     public static Map<String, Object> getPropertyMapByVertex(Vertex vertex) {
    Map<String, Object> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        if (vertex != null) {
            Iterator<VertexProperty<Object>> properties = vertex.properties();
            if (properties != null) {
                while (properties.hasNext()) {
                    Property<Object> property = properties.next();
                    propertyMap.put(property.key(), property.value());
                }
                propertyMap.put(GraphConstants.VERTEX_ID, vertex.id());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in getPropertyMapByVertex : {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }
    return propertyMap;
}
```

do we have some way to fast "getPropertyMapByVertex" method or any other way to fire query and get data quickly using java.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been following the development progress in JanusGraph, but if the `multiQuery` API is still available, you should give it a try:

```
List<Vertex> vertices = g.V().has('deleted',false).toList();
graph.multiQuery().addAllVertices(vertices).properties();
```

That's untested code written from memory, ultimately it may look a bit different.

However, since you mention that `g.V().has('deleted',false).toList()` is slow, but `g.V().has('deleted',false)` is fast, I'm not sure if you really understand what's going on. The latter statement by itself does absolutely nothing, while the former statement actually fetches all the vertices.